# RSpec "ideological" question: how to separate between test description and implementation

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, bdd

Read a lot of materials regarding the behavior-driven testing. Indeed, as it is stated (for example) [here](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/03/28/my-rspec-best-practices-and-tips/), the specs' code should be extremely readable, short and straightforward.

Now I have a question: suppose there are two kinds of team players: one is the developer, the other is a tester (QA). What would be the best test plan if not `describe` and `it` stubs, where all the `it`s are marked as *pending*? So, the QA might want to create such a *test plan* and pass it to the developer for the proper implementation.

After a few days, the tester (or product manager) wants to have a look on the tests. But... there is a hell of a code in there.

Hence, **the question**: is there a way to separate between the behavior specification and implementation in `RSpec`? I can fabricate a plenty of methods, but before inventing the wheel, I would rather prefer to stick to some common, proven and well-known practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as according to [The RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) **RSpec** is what developers manage for them internally, but **Cucumber** is what production manager and business can see. Think about RSpec as like internal tool to code coverage to see the objects internal behaviour: models, controllers, views. Other team members can see overall pictures that Cucumbers covers as well